# FOR Loop error "can't find file" and prematurely closing BAT file in Win10 CMD

Tags: for-loop, recursion, cmd

Longtime browser, first time poster...
I've searched and searched and cannot seem to solve this one.
I'm creating a large batch file and below is part of a larger file, but as tested standalone I still have the same issues. I'll try to keep this short and to the point:

This is for Folder AND File renaming by adding a "Prefix", and doing so recursively. That is the goal.
I need to do this all in a CMD prompt in Windows....I'm sure there are other ways of going about this, that's my limit for now.

My problem is this-- The 2nd FOR cmd, for the recursive file renaming, keeps closing the bat file.
Here is that specific line:

```
for /R %%F in (*) do ren "%%F" "%CN%_%%~nxF"
```

The bat file works just find when I use just the first FOR cmd (FOR /D) without the second FOR line allowed for the files.

At one point I briefly saw that it had an error...it flies by too fast to replicate...but it was something to the effect that 'file not found'.  However, it renames all of the files appropriately anyway.

First, I want to understand why an error even pops up.
Second, I would like the bat file to continue running.
What do I need to fix/address?

Here's the entire current bat file giving issues (there are some things in there for further dev...):

```
@echo off
cls
echo Renaming Utility
:CN
echo; 
set /P CN=Enter New Case Number: 
echo;
echo This is name you have selected: 
echo %CN%
echo; 
pause
echo;
::For Directories_Recursive
for /D /R %%F in (*) do ren "%%F" "%CN%_%%~nxF"
::For Files_Recursive
for /R %%F in (*) do ren "%%F" "%CN%_%%~nxF"
echo; 
echo Complete
echo; 
echo Press any key to exit.
pause >nul
```

Thx for your help in advance.  I'm very new to the FOR cmd...and have only really used bat files on
a limited basis in the past.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works better for you, as it should skip hidden/system files, over-write any diplicate named files, and also increase the cmd windows history to 9999 lines which will allow you to scroll back if there is an error.

```
@(SETLOCAL
  echo off
  cls
  MODE CON COLS=140 LINES=9999
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  EXIT /b
)

:Main
  echo.Renaming Utility
  REM CN
  echo. 
  set /P "CN=Enter New Case Number:  "
  echo.
  echo.This is name you have selected: 
  echo.%CN%
  echo.
  pause
  echo.
  REM For Directories_Recursive
  for /D /R %%F in (*) do ren "%%F" "%CN%_%%~nxF"
  REM For Files_Recursive changed to dir to ignore system and hidden files and changed to MOVE to overwrite read obly and duplicate FILES.
REM OLD FOR LOOP:   for /R %%F in (*) do ren "%%F" "%CN%_%%~nxF"
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
    Dir /S/B/A-D-S-H 
  ')  DO (
    MOVE /Y "%%_" "%%~dp_%CN%_%%~nx_"
  )
  echo.
  echo.Complete
  echo.
  echo.Press any key to exit.
  pause >nul
GOTO :eof
```